# RabbitMQ fails to start with persistence storage on Kubernetes. Permission denied error

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq, persistent-storage

I have a rabbit mq pod and I configured to use a persistence storage incase of pod restart/deletion by mounting a volume.

I configured everything but not able to get through this error:

```
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: 42: 
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: 
cannot create /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@reana-message-broker-5f45f797ff-cs79m.pid: 
Permission denied
```

Here're my config file and deployment app for kubernetes

1. `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# hadolint ignore=DL3009
RUN apt-get update
# hadolint ignore=DL3008
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends rabbitmq-server
RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean
# hadolint ignore=DL3001
RUN service rabbitmq-server start
COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 755 ./start.sh
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 15672
CMD ["/start.sh", "test", "1234"]
```

2. `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf <<EOF
listeners.tcp.default = 5672

default_user = <<"$1">>
default_pass = <<"$2">>
EOF
rabbitmq-server
```

3. `rabbitmq.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: message-broker
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 5672
     targetPort: 5672
     name: "tcp"
     protocol: TCP
   - port: 15672
     targetPort: 15672
     name: "management"
     protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: message-broker
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: message-broker
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: message-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: message-broker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: message-broker
        image: {{ .Values.message_broker.image }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.components.message_broker.imagePullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: tcp
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: management
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
        env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-secrets
              key: password # password = root
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-secrets
              key: user # user = root
      ...
      nodeSelector:
      ....
      volumes:
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          path: /var/test/rabbitmq
```

Let me know what I might be missing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume you mounted in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` is owned by root.

The rabbitmq process is running as `rabbitmq` user and doesn't have write access to this directory.

In your `start.sh` add:

```
chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

before starting the rabbitmq-server process.

Answer (score -1):

For me creating init container and running `command chmod -R 777 /var/lib/rabbitmq` did the trick. Even adding `RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` didn't fix the issue.

```
initContainers:
  - name: fix-volume-permissions
    image: {{ .Values.message_broker.image }}
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "chmod -R 777 /var/lib/rabbitmq" ]
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to do 777. You are also missing the problem here. When the container gets created, the folder inside of the container gets overwritten by the mounted folder, thats why your RUN did not work, because it gets overwritten when the container starts.

Answer (score -2):

The error says 'cannot create /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@reana-message-broker-5f45f797ff-cs79m.pid:
Permission denied'. Try providing write permission for /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/ directory.